# LinearLayout position is shifting to up , When video is playing in Videoview

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

When the application is launched layout is fine. But when the video is playing. the Layout of the button is moving up.
How to resolve this?
When the application is launched?[image]

When the video is playing the button is moving upwards [image]

Below I had placed the layoutfile.xml which i had been working on.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/VideoList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:foreground="@android:color/background_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </FrameLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the LinearLayout(that contains FrameLayout and Button) height match_parent

Answer (score 0):

No need for weight-sum, just make the layout_weights integers like 1 and 9 instead of 0.1 and 0.9

Also, fill_parent is deprecated, use match_parent instead.

You have a LinearLayout with single child. No need, just put ListView with same layout_params.

Lastly, your vertical LinearLayout on the right should have a height of match_parent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/VideoList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:foreground="@android:color/background_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </FrameLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Fixed layout Params on LinearLayout.

Comment: By using below layout code also. i used to get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/VideoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:foreground="@android:color/background_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <VideoView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </FrameLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have done changes in listview  "layout_width" and "layout_height" both should be match_parent ,Now it is working